# iOS 14 and Swift 5 Updates

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, mapbox-ios

I am a little bit lost. I have been working on a project for quite some time and when I updated to the latest Xcode  and updated to the recommended Swift 5 settings, I have had nothing but problems.

I am receiving errors like this:

[image: Screenshot of the errors]

After looking around online I found that I can get rid of this error:

```
Double-quoted include "pb.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead
```

by setting the "Quoted include in framework header" to "No"  in the build settings

[image: Double quoted error]

What have I done wrong and how can I fix these errors. They were not a problem last week so this is why I am confused.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you try pod repo update in terminal to update all your pods

Comment: @kjoe when I run 'pod repo update' it doesn't fix it sadly

Comment: Before up*grading* a project to a new SDK make sure that **all** dependencies are compatible, at least create a new branch in the source control to be able to return to the latest working version.

Comment: @vadian I know that now, if it is not up to date will it still be accepted on app store?

Comment: Run your app on an iOS 14 device. Does it refuse to launch? Certainly not.

Comment: @vadian when I revert back to the older version (Thankfully) I am asked to update to recommended settings. If I ignore this message will the app still be accepted?

Comment: It depends on whether the setting affects the required runtime for example an info.plist key. Once again if you app runs flawlessly on iOS 14 there is no need to release a new version immediately.